# How can I retrieve the hyper-parameters that were used to train this xgboost booster type model?

Tags: python, xgboost

I have an xgboost model that is trained already. It was trained by the xgboost original API. I am trying to find the hyper-parameters upon which the trained model was trained. Most specifically, I want to retrieve the objective of the trained model.

```
xgb.__versions__ # returns '1.7.2'
type(model) # returns xgboost.core.Booster
model.params() # AttibuteError: 'Booster' object has no attribute 'params'
model.get_params() # AttibuteError: 'Booster' object has no attribute 'get_params'
```

How can I retrieve the hyper-parameters that were used to train this xgboost booster type model?

Answer (score 0):

You may find these of interest.

```
model.attributes()

model.num_features

model.feature_names

model.feature_types
```

Also, several methods for persisting a model
can tell you about what it contains, including

- `.save_config`
- `.save_model`
- `.save_raw`

`.get_dump()`: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.get_dump

> ... the output format is primarily used for visualization or interpretation, hence it’s more human readable ...

---

[Let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) what you found!